# how to print numpy arrays with stats

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, statistics

Currently in a programming class going over numpy arrays. i currently have an array printing going 10,20,30 etc... and need to get statistics for it

```
import numpy as np

SIZE = 10

numbers = np.array([0] * SIZE, dtype=int)

print("All the numbers...")
print(numbers)
print()

for i in range(SIZE):
    numbers[i] = (i+1) * 10

print("All the numbers...")
for i in range(SIZE):
    print(numbers[i], end= " ")
```

this is what i used to do so but now I need to print min , max, total, and average. I understand the equation set ups needed to achieve all four but im lost when my teacher requires us to print said stats like this

```
print("Min: ", stats[0])
print("Max: ", stats[1])
print("Total: ", stats[2])
print("Average: ", stats[3])    
print()
```

with it being stats[1] , stats[2] and so on does this mean I put all of my equations into the original np.array for this or do I create an np.array of a size of 4 then somehow put said equations into the array using stat[1] and so on?
sorry if the question is confusing I am still trying to figure out how to word these kinds of questions.

Comment: I'm sorry, but we can only guess what your teacher *expects* you to do. I guess they expected to you put those statistics in another array, which you assign to the `stats` variable. But you should probably ask your teacher

Comment: nah not asking for specific code just guidance. just want to hear wether youd do something like seperate stats variables and or keep it all together. Thanks for responding

Comment: I'm sorry, but please read the [help] and [ask]. Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions, not guidance on doing your homework. Again, you probably should ask your teacher for guidance on this assignment

Answer (score 0):

you would create a new array called "stats" and put the values in there. but they're not equations in there, they're just numbers.

```
stats=[0 for i in range(4)]

stats[0]=min(numbers)
stats[1]=max(numbers)
stats[2]=sum(numbers)
stats[3]=np.mean(numbers)
```